# Using a BAT file as service with NSSM

Tags: cmd, nssm

I am writing a `.BAT` script which goes as follows:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\WinRAR"

winrar.exe
```

Double clicking this batch file works fine and openes winrar for me....now i try installing it as service with NSSM

i place `nssm.exe` in the same directory as my batch file and proceed to install it like following:

[image]

[image]

All other tabs are left unchanged. when I open `services.msc` and manually click `start` on this service it shows `running` but nothing happens. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?

Comment: I'll start by asking you a question. How many services do you know, or have, which run with a visible window?

Comment: oh wait i feel so dumb now.....winrar acually opens if i see in task manager....sorry I am pretty new to this.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was a simple misunderstanding of the concept, and the OP has acknowledged it. Keeping this question open adds no value to others, in fact it may detract from what people may be looking for

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for asking this dumb question....it actually runs in baground like all services.